# Traversing array and changing object values

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to update the values ​​of my `payments` array objects

```
{
    "balance": 109610,
    "gifts": [],
    "orders": [],
    "payments": [{
        "isPaid": 0,
        "status": "Pending",
        "address": "3KsdQbmADyz1KNN7qqX1yZcMXBbfFCm31r",
        "date": 1624057559970
    }, {
        "isPaid": 0,
        "status": "Pending",
        "address": "3FYQK6YiAaL8fEbDWaXYw38CJN3K2y5dPD",
        "date": 1624058531601
    }],
    "isVendedor": false,
    "isAdmin": true,
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2021-06-17T21:10:15.020Z"
    },
    "username": "teste",
    "email": "teste@teste.com",
    "password": "$2a$10$qUNkorDuvbf.AYLTvjNc4ebKyNgLa7L9NoTBwAIV8.BfN51umaD9O",
    "__v": 3
}
```

First, I look for the object of the user who made a request to my server

```
const userPayment = await User.find({"payments.address": notification.address}).exec();
```

Then I go through the user object and find it until I find the position where I find `notification.address` again

```
  userPayment.forEach((AllPayments, index) => {
    AllPayments.payments.forEach((payment, index) => {
      if (payment.address == notification.address) {
        if (payment.isPaid || payment.status != "Pending")
          return res.json({
            success: false,
            error: "Payment Already Processed!",
          });

        const valueToDeposit = Math.round(notification.fiat_amount);

        console.log(
          userPayment[0].payments[index].isPaid,
          userPayment[0].payments[index].status
        );

        // Set payments[index].isPaid = true
       // Set payments[index].status = "Paid"
    });
  });
```

So I tried to make these 3 ways and none of them was successful.

```
userPayment[0].balance += valueToDeposit; // this works when save() is triggered
userPayment[0].payments[index].isPaid = 1; //  this doesnt works when save() is triggered
userPayment[0].payments[index].status = "Paid"; // this doesnt works when save() is triggered

userPayment[0].updateOne({"payments.address": notification.address}, { $set: { "payments.$.isPaid": 1,"payments.$.status":"Paid" } },(err, result) => { console.log(err, result); }); this doesnt works

userPayment[0].save()
```

Comment: What doesn't work in your last way? As I know, it should work.

Comment: You are referring to the ``save()`` or ``updateOne()`` method?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read it carefully. You can use `User.updateMany({"payments.address": notification.address}, { $set: { "payments.$.isPaid": 1,"payments.$.status":"Paid" })`